# Validating input data with BreezeJS / KnockoutJS / Durandal

Tags: asp.net, html, knockout.js, breeze, durandal

I'm trying to validate my inputs from a form with BreezeJS / KnockoutJS / Durandal and I'm not getting any results.

This is my input inside my view:

```
<input data-bind="value:app_name, attr: {placeholder: resources.brand_create_placeholder_brand_name }" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="app_name" id="app_name" />
```

And this is my viewmodel:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'services/logger', 'plugins/router', 'knockout', 'breeze', 'toastr', 'services/resources'],
    function (app, logger, router, ko, breeze, toastr, resourcesSVC) {

    var vm = {

        app_name: ko.observable(), //.extend({ required: true, minLength: 30, }),
        ...,
        currency: ko.observable(),
        currencies: [{ name: "Euro", value: "EUR", synbol: "€" }, { name: "Dollar", value: "USD", synbol: "$" }, { name: "Pounds Sterling", value: "GBP", synbol: "£" }],
        use_smtp: ko.observable(false),

        activate: activate,
        title: "Create Brand",
        createEntity: createEntity,
        goBack: goBack,

        resources: {}
        }
    };
```

Here I'm initializing my service:

```
var serviceName = 'breeze';
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
```

And here I have the creation of my entity:

```
function createEntity() {

    var DT = breeze.DataType;
    var Validator = breeze.Validator;

    var brand = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("app");

    /*app_name*/
    var propAppName = brand.getProperty('app_name');
    brand.addValidator(Validator.required(), propAppName);
    brand.addValidator(Validator.maxLength({ maxLength: 30 }), propAppName);

    var newBrand = brand.createEntity('app');

    newBrand.app_name = vm.app_name();
    ...
    manager.addEntity(newBrand);
    manager.saveChanges()
        .then(createSucceeded)
        .fail(createFailed);

    function createSucceeded(data) {
        toastr.success("Brand created");
        app.trigger('brand:changed');
        router.navigate('#brands');
    }

    function createFailed(error) {
        var msgError = "Create failed: " + getErrorMessages(error);
        toastr.error(msgError);
        manager.rejectChanges();
    }
}
```

Can you please help me set validators for each field & display a custom message for each one whose values aren't correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the commented out code valuable to the sample code? If so, add information about what part fails (if this is your attempted solution) ,if not please delete it.

Comment: Tanner is right I don't see any validation logic in your code besides commented out stuff...

Comment: Sorry guys, I've already updated the code. The commented code were some of my attemps.